# Determine angle between 2 vectors.

Tags: vectors, angle

If there are two vectors given
$$\vec {OA} = \hat i + 2\hat j~~\text{and}~~\vec {OB} = 4\hat i + p\hat k $$

Then find the values of $p$ for which $\angle AOB = \cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{5})$.

Would someone please give me a hand on solving this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

Try to use Dot product rule.which is
$$\vec A. \vec B=|\vec A|.|\vec B|.cos \theta $$
Here,
$$\vec A= \hat i + 2\hat j,\vec B=4\hat i + p\hat k$$
$$|\vec A|=\sqrt{1^2+2^2}=\sqrt{5}~~,~~|\vec B|=\sqrt{16+p^2}$$
$$\theta=\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{5})$$

If you substitute everything in the formula I think you will get, $$p=\pm 8$$

Comment: Assalamualikum! it will be great if you show me substituted form, Thanks brother!

Comment: At last you should get something like $4=\sqrt{5}.\sqrt{16+p^2}.\cos\bigg(\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{5})\bigg)$

Comment: Thank you so much man! I was stuck at the theta step, i forgot to put cos!

Comment: welcome to MSE family.